# How to prevent stretching, blurring and pixelating of embedded logos in VirtualDub?

Tags: video, processing, encoding, virtualdub, watermark

take a look at this please http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=te-HVN8y_QE&hd=1 .

Notice the embedded "logo" in the upper left corner? How blurry and pixelated it is?

This is the original image:

[image]

The stretching, blurring, pixelating etc. most likely comes from resizing the original video from 1920x1200 to 1280x720 and encoding it with h.264.

Can anyone tell me how I can prevent the blurring, unsharpening and pixelating and retain their original quality?

How do I exclude the logo from the whole encoding process and just slap it there in its original format and form?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I exclude the logo from the whole encoding process and just slap it there in its original format and form?

You would need to do that in the video player itself, eg. using a Flash player that allows play-time watermarking or with another element over an HTML5 `<video>`.

Naturally, you don't get this option with YouTube.

To generally improve quality:

- add the logo overlay with a logo filter running *after* the resize filter;
- consider uploading an SD version that you have resized to YouTube's native on-page video resolution yourself (laying the logo on top after the resize);
- use a logo that compresses better. A simpler soft-edged semi-opaque white overlay is likely to survive compression better than the highly-saturated sharp red-and-black logo you have at the moment.

Comment: Worth a try, haven't thought of applying the image AFTER I've resized and encoded the whole video.

Comment: Nope, applying the image AFTER resizing and encoding didn't help.

Comment: Well you can't apply the image *after* encoding (without player support as noted above). You would have to encode it again, causing a quality loss in the entire video. You would certainly obtain better quality from applying a logo after resizing, although the quality improvement may be small compared to the general quality of the lossy compression.

Comment: Yea, I know, I tried both methods to no avail. Still bad logo quality :(.

Guess I'll have to redo the logo...